# Difficulties getting an if...else statement to work inside a function

Tags: javascript

I know I am very close, but I can't get the code to return anything but the 'savesTheDay' variable in the else option.I don't think I'm setting up my if....else conditionals properly. I think should be going with the "happy ending" for the `if` statement (in my case, the `savesTheDay` variable? Should I not define 'dangerLevel' inside the function since I want it to change? Thanks!

**Edited:
I am trying to get each of the phases to return when I call the assessSituation function. I can only get the saveTheDay message to return, even if the value is outside of the parameters of the condition i.e. assessSituation(1);. I'd expect to get the "Meh. Hard Pass." return value instead of saveTheDay.

Added new code, still isn't running though!**

```
function assessSituation (dangerLevel, saveTheDay, badExcuse) {

  var saveTheDay = "Crime won't stand a chance against me!";
  var dangerLevel = dangerLevel; 
  var badExcuse = "I'm scared, I've never gone up against this many villains";
  
  if (10 < dangerLevel < 50) {
    console.log(saveTheDay);
  } else if (dangerLevel > 50) {
      console.log(badExcuse);
    } else 
    console.log("Meh. Hard Pass.");
    }
```

Comment: What are you after?

Comment: Why are you reassigning the variable that was received as a parameter?

Comment: The `else` part is never reached.

Comment: You can't have a condition in `else`. It doesn't need a condition because it's run when none of the previous conditions were true.

Comment: "Should I not define 'dangerLevel' inside the function since I want it to change?" Yes, you should not define it. It's overwriting the argument.

Comment: What did you intend with that declaration? How did you expect your function to process the argument?

Comment: I would suggest you study again how to write ```if``` statements and then learn how to write functions

Comment: Is it supposed to be a default value if the caller omits the argument?

Comment: You have the same problem with the other 2 variables.

Comment: What happens f the danger level is exactly 50? An else condition does not have a clause.

Comment: `var dangerLevel = 10;` <--- why are you always setting it to 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript, like many other languages (C/C++, Java, etc.) except Python, does not have support for chaining comparison operators.

```js
10 < dangerLevel < 50
```

is equivalent to

```js
(10 < dangerLevel /* true or false */) < 50
(true) < 50
// or
(false) < 50
```

Since `false == 0` and `true == 1`, the result will always be `true` since `0` and `1` are both less than `50`.

To fix your logic, use the `&&` (AND) operator:

```js
if ((10 < dangerLevel) && (dangerLevel < 50))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only returning saveTheDay because it's the only conditional that is matched.

Your dangerLevel = 10, so dangerLevel is not > 50, and it's not smaller than 10, but it's definitely < 50. If you want another return you can change dangerLevel before if else clause.

Ps:  I didn't see that your variable inside your function has the same name of the input. You should choose another name if you want to have both

Answer (score 0):

If you’re passing dangerLevel into the function, you’re overwriting it when you create the dangerLevel variable inside the function.  Remove “var dangerLevel = 10” and see if the output you get is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still getting the same answer without the variable having a value in the function. Reposted my modified code above.

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting conditons. (dangerLevel<50) and (dangerLevel<10) so when your code runs with dangerLevel=10 its doesn't know wich one to choose. I suggest you remplace (dangerLevel<50) to (10<=dangerLevel<=50)

Comment: I was getting errors when I had (10=<dangerLevel=<50) in my code so I modified it and took var dangerLevel= 10 out and I'm still having the same issues. Reposted above. thanks!

Comment: (10<=dangerLevel<=50)* my mistake. Try this and I'm sure it'll work now

Answer (score 0):

you are setting dangerLevel = 10;

it doesn't matter what you pass in, 10 gets populated for dangerLevel, so:

10 will never be > 50
will never be <10
wil always be < 50

which is why you always get savesTheDay

Comment: I am still getting the same return when I took out the value in the dangerLevel variable.

Comment: what danger level are you passing in? By the way you have a gap in your logic where if dangerLevel == 50, it falls through the gap